# Should Cross Validated participate in the “Winter Bash” Holiday hats promotion (2012)?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

The Stack Exchange team is organizing an original event, in the spirit of the one organized last year on the [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) site, called [**Hat Dash**](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".

This event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available. 
The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.
Participation on one site does not affect accounts on other SE sites.

The following two answers aim to collect votes for a community poll: Please, indicate whether you think *Cross Validated* should participate to this event or not (1 vote per user). Responses from the community users are due by November, 28 (sorry for the short delay), and moderators will inform the SE team of our collective decision.

Comment: Two things to note: (1) Hats are ***ephemeral*** -- they will last only as long as the event runs. (2) Effectively, ***hats are badges you can wear***. They are earned by doing a certain amount of specific site actions. Also, and I can't emphasize this enough: ***individuals CAN opt out!*** Meaning, if you hate hats, you can choose not to see them. However, users who stumble across your site around New Year's Eve *will* see them. The choice is yours, CV community! I think it's harmless fun, but I also understand that this is a site for professionals.

Comment: Voting is now over. Happy hat hunting!

Comment: @mbq, according to this, the promo starts on 12/19. How come you already have a hat?

Comment: @gung This is my private hat; I just change the gravatar for xmas.

Comment: @mbq, Merry X-mas!

Comment: Ok...these hats are quite fun.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Yes**, Cross Validated should participate in Winter Bash 2012.

Comment: Hi, @chl. Consider accepting this answer to make this thread appear resolved.

Comment: Thanks, @amoeba! This is done now.

Answer (score 12):

**No**, Cross Validated should not participate in Winter Bash 2012.

Comment: Note: It's only winter in half of the world.

Comment: @Glen_b Fortunately, not *all* of the hats are winter-themed. Some are, some are less seasonal. :) There's even a pair of sunglasses!