# Should Cross Validated participate in the 2014 “Winter Bash”?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winterbash

**[For the third year running](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486), the Stack Exchange team is organizing a "Winter Bash".**  Users earn "hats" for their gravatars by completing novel tasks (analogous to badges). Certain specific actions will trigger access to a (graphical) hat, which their gravatar can then "wear" at the user's option.

This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Individuals who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available (which will cause you not to see hats at all). The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer. Participation on one site does not affect accounts on other SE sites.

Two answers aim to collect votes for a community poll: **Please, indicate whether you think Cross Validated should participate in this event or not** (1 vote per user). Responses from the community are due by November 30.  Moderators will inform the SE team of our collective decision.

Comment: I imagine I'll probably end up abstaining from this vote\*, but I do greatly appreciate that we get the opportunity to choose, and that there's also the chance to opt out individually.  \*(I'm fairly relaxed about the outcome - happy with whichever way people in Cross Validated decide to go, though judging from my past behaviour I'll most likely participate if it runs.)

Comment: I like how @Glen_b is even a statistician in evaluating his own decisions: all that matters observable data, not his present/future preferences.

Comment: Two quick questions: What sort of "actions" and are the hats only visible for the duration of the event?

Comment: @Steve The actions vary, but typically are akin to the kinds of site interactions used to earn badges. Many of these actions are announced in advance but some are kept secret.  Hats--and all associated statistical summaries--are visible only for the duration. All are rewards; none are punishments. The slight visual change they create on the site adds a little variety. For the first year I had some concern that this "bash" would look a little unprofessional, but it's not.

Comment: @SteveS http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/ shows the hats that were available in 2013.

Comment: Based on the results of this voting, I have notified the SE team that CV opts to participate in this event.

Comment: [featured] can be removed and [status-completed] added, since the Dec 1 deadline has passed.

Comment: @whuber: do you want to put up a similar poll question about us participating in the [2015 winter bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you; the mods are working on it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Yes**, Cross Validated should participate in Winter Bash 2014.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, Cross Validated should not participate in Winter Bash 2014.